# How to efficiently pull out the running balance of a huge table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a huge table that contains all the sales entries that have been made. Since this is a supermarket chain the number of entries in the table is very huge. We are planning to address this issue by creating a new database and sales table. So I wanted to know what is an effective way that we can store the below info

```
sl date customer_id inv_number items_json  amount
```

So that we can easily pull out the cumulative sum of the amounts for all entries for a period? For instance, if I select the period as 1 Jan 2022 to 3 Jan 2022, then I would need all entries during the period with the total as on 1 Jan 2022 (so that we can start adding the transaction amount to it) and the total as on 3 Jan 2022 (Which will be the total as on 1 Jan + all amount between 1st and 3rd Jan)

So the result I need is:
if the opening total is 1000

```
sl  date  customer_id  inv_number  amount  total
44  1 Jan    999          101       100     1100
45  1 Jan    999          102      200      1300
```

What is the efficient way of maintaining this table? Do I need to create any view or triggers to achieve this?

Comment: What do you consider "*huge*"?

Comment: @J.D. about 50-100k rows each day.

Comment: What is an "sl"?

Comment: its just serial number (Sl. No)

Comment: Do you need to store the total in the database, or just retrieve it from a query? If you don't need to store the total, then you could query using a windowing function to sum over the date to give a running total.